# trouble in setting rotation orientation in animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have 2 UIView and I want to rotate them in different orientation. Here is my code

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // middleView and bigView are outlets of UIView
    self.middleView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
    self.bigView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI);
}

- (IBAction)smallTouched:(id)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.middleView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
        self.bigView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);

    }];
}
```

And the two view both rotate in anti-clock orientation. I don't know why.

Comment: Your code says both views to rotate from pi to zero. What did you expect?

Comment: @cahn Sorry,I type wrong.One is pi to zero.The other is -pi to zero.I have edited.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but did you try CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-0) for the middeView?  According to the docs, the sign of the angle determines the direction of rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because sin(PI) == sin(-PI) and cos(PI) == cos(-PI), `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI)` equals `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI)`. You could try `M_PI * 179.9 / 180` and `-M_PI * 179.9 / 180` or something similar.